# PyroCMS: how to share resources between modules?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, pyrocms

I'm new to PyroCMS and struggling to get help on the forums (slow responses, minimal activity, etc.). So, I'm hoping someone here on SO can help.

**How do I share resources (e.g. models, controllers, views, etc.) between modules?** It seems that every module is self contained and cannot access other modules' resources. This is going to cause a problem for us.

I do not like the idea of putting these common resources in the main PyroCMS installation. This seems architecturally wrong to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PyroCMS uses [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home), so accessing resources from other modules is easy.

Let's say you want to load the model `navigation_m`:

This will work from within the `navigation` module (where it resides):

```
$this->load->model('navigation_m');
```

This will work from anywhere:

```
$this->load->model('navigation/navigation_m');
```

That's it! No need to include the `model/` path, the loader takes care of it for you. Same applies to language files, libraries, and other resources.

Comment: thanks. This now means that certain modules will be dependent on other modules for certain resources. Do you see a problem with this?

Comment: If I was writing a drop-in module for Pyro I'd totally avoid dependency on other modules unless they are "core" modules and you *know* they will always be available, but if it's just for my application I wouldn't worry too much. Less dependency is better, but sometimes it's the only way to avoid code duplication. Just don't get wrapped too tight around other resources.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to create a module with multiple sub-menus? Say I am creating a "Content" module and want the sub-menus "Comments" and "Files" -- could I somehow make those 2 sub-menus appear from one module only? The reason I need to develop multiple modules is merely for those sub-menus. Seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, sounds like a separate question (and sounds like not a great idea, as you already seem to think).